# How to add 3 if an if statement is met (Unity3d)

Tags: if-statement, unity-game-engine

i am trying to make an if statment that adds 3 to an iteger every time the if statment is met. I know how to add 1 using `coins++` but is there a way to add 3.

```
if (other.tag == "yes") 
{
  coins + 3;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
coins += 3;
```

is a more compact way than `coins = coins + 3;`.